# code that I can run, or a plug in to show what sql tables something pulls information from

Tags: php, plugin-development, database, plugin-recommendation

Does anyone know if there is some code I can run, or create or a plug in in existence where I can click "run" or see a display showing what sql tables a page is pulling from? For example an ordering plug in that saves to multiple tables. Is there a way I can track that down more easily? The plug in creator was not helpful.

For example a plug in called "waht teh file" shows what parts are making up the page. Is there something like this or can I make something like this to show where sql data is coming from? [image]

Comment: Try "Query Monitor".

Comment: thank you so much. Exactly what I needed